# AWS EC2 with Amazon Linux install OpenVPN that works perfect but after a restart it doesent work - WHY?

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, openvpn

I have searched on google but I don't have found an answer to my problem.

**Problem:** I have an AWS EC2 server running Open VPN. I have a Windows 10 client. I restart the complete AWS EC2 server with "sudo reboot" and after the restarting the client (Windows 10) can connect but I cannot open any website I get a timeout.

(OpenVPN after restart the EC2 server let me connect (client) but I can not open any websites). Now I try it here.

I get followed log on the client:

```
Sun May 14 20:10:28 2017 disabling NCP mode (--ncp-disable) because not in P2MP client or server mode
Sun May 14 20:10:28 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.2 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on May 11 2017
Sun May 14 20:10:28 2017 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
Sun May 14 20:10:28 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.10
Enter Management Password:
Sun May 14 20:10:28 2017 open_tun
Sun May 14 20:10:28 2017 TAP-WIN32 device [Ethernet 2] opened: \\.\Global\{5E768F9D-FF78-47F1-A881-B6F6132019B6}.tap
Sun May 14 20:10:28 2017 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.4.0.2/255.255.255.252 on interface {5E768F9D-FF78-47F1-A881-B6F6132019B6} [DHCP-serv: 10.4.0.1, lease-time: 31536000]
Sun May 14 20:10:29 2017 Successful ARP Flush on interface [8] {5E768F9D-FF78-47F1-A881-B6F6132019B6}
Sun May 14 20:10:29 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sun May 14 20:10:29 2017 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]ec2-ip:1194
Sun May 14 20:10:29 2017 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]ec2-ip:1194 [nonblock]
Sun May 14 20:10:30 2017 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]ec2-ip:1194
Sun May 14 20:10:30 2017 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Sun May 14 20:10:30 2017 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]ec2-ip:1194
Sun May 14 20:10:39 2017 Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]ec2-ip:1194
Sun May 14 20:10:45 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

My configuration is the same as http://envyandroid.com/setup-free-private-vpn-on-amazon-ec2/

```
port 1194
proto tcp-server
dev tun1
ifconfig 10.4.0.1 10.4.0.2
status server-tcp.log
verb 3
secret ovpn.key
push dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
push dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4
cipher AES-256-CBC
```

Client config is:

```
proto tcp-client
remote ec2-ip
port 1194
dev tun
secret ovpn.key
redirect-gateway def1
ifconfig 10.4.0.2 10.4.0.1
cipher AES-256-CBC
```

SERVER LOG:

```
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 disabling NCP mode (--ncp-disable) because not in P2MP client or server mode
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.1 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [Fedora EPEL patched] [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Apr  3 2017
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013, LZO 2.06
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 Outgoing Static Key Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 Outgoing Static Key Encryption: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 Incoming Static Key Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 Incoming Static Key Encryption: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 local 10.4.0.1 peer 10.4.0.2
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Sun May 14 21:23:10 2017 Listening for incoming TCP connection on [AF_INET][undef]:1194
Sun May 14 21:24:32 2017 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]:50479
Sun May 14 21:24:32 2017 TCPv4_SERVER link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
Sun May 14 21:24:32 2017 TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [AF_INET]my-windows10-local-ip:50479
Sun May 14 21:24:32 2017 Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]my-windows10-local-ip:50479
Sun May 14 21:24:33 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Output from command "iptables-save":

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.18 on Sun May 14 23:02:24 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [122:6630]
:INPUT ACCEPT [7:360]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [95:6264]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [95:6264]
-A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/2 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/2 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/2 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/2 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/2 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/2 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/2 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/2 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/2 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/2 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/2 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/2 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun May 14 23:02:24 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.18 on Sun May 14 23:02:24 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [634:91381]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [639:54866]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun May 14 23:02:24 2017
```

Output of "sysctl -a | grep forward":

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                                
net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                             
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                            
net.ipv4.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                         
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                               
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.mc_forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                            
net.ipv4.conf.lo.forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                                 
net.ipv4.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                              
net.ipv4.conf.tun1.forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                               
net.ipv4.conf.tun1.mc_forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                            
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0                                                                                                                                                                                         
net.ipv4.ip_forward_use_pmtu = 0                                                                                                                                                                                
error: "Input/output error" reading key "net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret"
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                                
net.ipv6.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                             
error: "Input/output error" reading key "net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret"
error: "Input/output error" reading key "net.ipv6.conf.eth0.stable_secret"
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                            
net.ipv6.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                         
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                               
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mc_forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                            
error: "Input/output error" reading key "net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret"
net.ipv6.conf.lo.forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                                 
net.ipv6.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                              
net.ipv6.conf.tun1.forwarding = 0                                                                                                                                                                               
net.ipv6.conf.tun1.mc_forwarding = 0
```

I hope I can with your help find a solution.

Comment: Suggest your edit your question to add a bit more detail. Is EC2 the client or the server? What are you restarting?

Comment: I restart the complete AWS EC2 server with "sudo reboot" and after the restarting the client (Windows 10) can connect but I cannot open any website I get a timeout.

Comment: So, you're using OpenVPN on an EC2 server, basically as a proxy. You restart the W10 client and the server, and you can't access the internet any more. What happens if you restart only the server, or the client? It'd be easier to solve if you can narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Could you share logs from server side?

Comment: I have to try to restart my Windows 10 Notebook but this not help. I have the same problem that I can connect but I can't  open any website. Without restart of the EC2 server, I can reboot my Windows 10 Notebook and I connect successful with website access. But when I restart the EC2 server then doesen't work again. The OpenVPN server log have I attached to  my origin posting.

Comment: I have this also tested with Digital Ocean CentOS server same config as the EC2 server after a restart of the server then I have the same problem. I can connect but I cannot open any Website. The Icon of OpenVPN client on my Windows 10 machine is green.

Comment: Big picture question: why are you doing this? There are plenty of VPN providers that will do the job cheaper than having an EC2 server. Of course if you already have an EC2 server that's cheaper.

Comment: When I use AWS light sail then costs me the server only $5 with 1TB traffic and I simply do not trust the other providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problems with OpenVPN configuration, so I think, there is problem with iptables configuration. It could be not saved after deploy and now your nat section is empty, that's why you can't access any web-site.

**Update** problem was with disabled forwarding. There is need add to `/etc/sysctl.conf` string `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, to persistent forwarding settings.

Comment: What must I do to get rid of this? I have try "service iptables save" but after a restart of the server then I have the same problem that I can not exist any website. Please help me.

Comment: @sm_a Please share output for `iptables-save` command after restart.

Comment: the iptables-save command output have I added to my origin post. Hope you find a solution.

Comment: @sm_a Well, you have configured MASQARADE. So my point is wrong. But may be you have disabled forwarding? Please share output for `sysctl -a | grep forward`.

Comment: the output of "sysctl -a | grep forward" I have attached to my origin post. Hope you find the failure.

Comment: @sm_a Bingo, you have disabled forwarding! Try to execute `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and try to connect to Web-site. If it help, then add to `/etc/sysctl.conf` string `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.

Comment: Yes, you have right - now it works. But how to make this persistent after a restart?

Comment: @sm_a add to `/etc/sysctl.conf` string `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, as I mentioned below.

Comment: sorry I have not seen that you have it answered in the answer before.